# fill out form using vba and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vba, firefox, browser-automation

currently i can accomplish this using IE

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Navigate "www.google.com"
ie.document.getElementByID("blah").value = "blah"
```

im curious if there is a way to navigate to website and fill out info using other than IE with VBA for example with FireFox or Chrome

i know how to navigate to other websites using any of the explorers for example Chrome as per below, but i would like to know how can fill out fields like search field on www.google.com using Chrome

```
call Shell("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"& " " & URL)
```

Comment: I don't think either FF or Chrome expose the same type of COM automation interface as IE.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [Selenium wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/) to drive Chrome or Firefox (or PhantomJS). Note that it is currently in beta. Once it is installed, either add a reference to Selenium Type Library or use late binding (example below).

In my (very) limited tests, the only noticeable difference is the couple seconds it takes to load the driver.

Here is a simple example from the link above (modified to use late binding) that fills out the search field in Google and clicks the search button:

```
Dim selDriver As Object
Set selDriver = CreateObject("Selenium.WebDriver"）

selDriver.Start "chrome", "http://www.google.com/"
selDriver.Open "http://www.google.com"
selDriver.Type "name=q", "Eiffel Tower"
selDriver.Click "name=btnG"

selDriver.stop
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016, the Selenium wrapper was moved to Github instead of the above Google address. Additionally, if you're using Chrome you'll want to update the web driver for Google Chrome [here](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/154).

[Selenium Basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic)

After downloading these items you'll then need to follow the instructions above for adding the library to in your Visual Basic Editor from within Excel. Afer doing so, you should be able fill out a web form using vba and chrome as originally requested.

Comment: This answer is extremely vague and risks being flagged and deleted. Please edit to contain more context than a single link -- explain what Selenium is, and how to use it to accomplish the specific goal using the straw example the questioner used.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've updated my comment and provided additional context. If this is still not enough context please share some example responses for me to model, alternatively, let me know if it also makes sense. This helps me improve my information sharing techniques.