# Javascript Injection in Chrome with Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, google-chrome, excel

I am trying to inject a search criteria or log-in or whatever into a Chrome window using VBA. In IE this exercise isn't difficult since IE is the top level object in the DOM. Totally confused using a shell function in VBA what the document object model looks like at the top to access the open window. Here is my example code

```
Function sparkroomInChrome()

  Dim chromePath As String

  chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""

  Shell (chromePath & " -url https://google.com

End Function

Function userCredentials()

     document.getElementsByClassName("gsfi")[0].value = "cats";

End Function
```

Any guidance would be super appreciated on this or any insight for other similar solutions. Thank you.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but you're missing an end-quote and a closing parenthesis on the `Shell` command. Not sure if that's a copy/paste error or not.

Comment: Unlike IE Chrome does not have a COM automation interface, you cannot interact with its DOM from VBA.

Comment: What about [selenium](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/)? On [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750943/fill-out-form-using-vba-and-chrome).

Comment: Can you check "Selenium VBA" option, https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/

From site::: Selenium VBA is a Windows COM library that uses the popular Selenium web testing tool.
It makes it possible to automate web browsing using Excel and VBA code or using a simple VBS file executed by double-clicking on it.
User's actions can be recorded using the Firefox plugin named "Selenium IDE" and translated to VBA or VBS with the provided formatters.

Comment: I can support @dee that you should go with Selenium with this. I usually use PhantomJS browser with Selenium to keep it invisible and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Using Selenium VBA to achieve your task.

1) Download and install “Selenium Wrapper Library” latest version -> site: https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/

2) Open Excel - Go to "Tools -> References.." in VBA

3) Select “Selenium Type Library” - in References

[image]

4) Try below sample code.

```
Public Sub Search_4_Cat()

  Dim selenium As New Selenium.WebDriver

  selenium.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com/", False
  selenium.Open "https://www.google.com/"
  selenium.Type "name=q", "Cat"
  selenium.Click "name=btnG"

  'selenium.stop          ' this will close the browser

End Sub
```

For more details check: https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/